# How is the txpool synced between nodes in a web3 JSON RPC provider?

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, txpool

From my understanding, there is a bit of state which is held on a node when interacting with it over JSON RPC. One of these states local to the node is the txpool. The txpool is exposed with the `web3.eth.getTransaction(txHash)` method. It returns a transaction where `transaction.blockHash == null` if the transaction is in the txPool and returns `transaction == null` when the transaction is unknown.

If a `sendTransaction` call is made to one node followed by a `getTransaction` call to another node, with the transaction hash returned from `sendTransaction`, a null transaction will be returned because the transaction is only in the first node's txpool and the second node knows nothing about it.

What do services like myetherwallet do to ensure that sessions are maintained across requests so things like this don't happen? Is there a way to synchronize the transaction pools?

Answer (score 2):

It's a complex question, i use the briefest description as far as possible. At first `read the facking source code`.

**Broadcats Transaction**. In [handler.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/eth/handler.go#L732) file, there is a `txBroadcastLoop` method, the function of it is sending a local transaction to peers of connected, when a transaction committed, this method would be called by event. by [BroadcastTx](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/eth/handler.go#L708) method, this tx will be delivered to peers by p2p network, if you have interest to analysis it, please read source file to know how p2p network created, connected, receive or send message.

**Receive transaction**. The same source file handler.go, you can find a [handleMsg](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/eth/handler.go#L650) method, it's duty is receive message from connected peers. On lines 650, there is the logic dealing with remote transaction. At first, this txs will be marked remote transaction, because there is a especial judgement, for example, drop remote transactions under our own minimal accepted gas price, etc. And then, this remote txs will be added to `tx_pool`, before added `tx_pool`, there is so many validating, you can find a detail adding logic about transaction pool in source file [tx_pool.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/master/core/tx_pool.go#L694).

Hope it helps~